# Google Cloud Logging: No LogEntry using project as resource name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

REST method[1] used.
Request:

```
{
  "resourceNames": [
    "projects/[PROJECT_ID]"
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "nextPageToken": "..."
}
```

But when alternative resource specified in format

```
projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/[LOCATION_ID]/buckets/[BUCKET_ID]/views/[VIEW_ID]
```

log entries returned.
Is any way to get the logs using short resource format?

1. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick (!?) is to add a filter that captures log entries, perhaps:

```
{
  "resourceNames": [
    "projects/[[PROJECT_ID]]"
  ],
  "filter": "timestamp>=\"2021-09-02T15:00:00.000000Z\""
}
```

And using `pageSize`

One way to verify this is to have `gcloud` show the underlying `--log-http` call:

```sh
gcloud logging read \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--log-http
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
[[REDACTED]]
== headers end ==
== body start ==
{"filter": "timestamp>=\"2021-09-02T15:00:00.000000Z\"", "orderBy": "timestamp desc", "pageSize": 1000, "resourceNames": ["projects/${PROJECT}"]}
== body end ==
```

Comment: Using 'timestamp' filter it works. Same time additional filter queries won't without 'timestamp'.